# UUID is not working in android api 23 and higher what is the solution

Tags: android, bluetooth

this works fine in api lower then 23 but not in 23 and higher i also tried; 
this is a basic UUID;

```
private static final UUID MY_UUID_INSECURE = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
```

Bluetooth Socket by creating Insecure:

```
mBluetoothServerSocket = mBlurtoothSocket.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(My_UUID_INSECURE);
```

this also gives the same result. I also tried Bluetooth Socket by creat RFcomm:

```
mBluetoothServerSocket = mBlurtoothSocket.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(My_UUID_INSECURE);`
```

Using wifiManager to get the mac address of device:

```
WifiManager manager = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo info = manager.getConnectionInfo();
String address = info.getMacAddress();
```

Try to convert Mac address into `UUID`, but this gives an invalid mac address

```
My_UUID_INSECURE = UUID.fromString(address);
```

Comment: "Not working"? Stacktrace please.

Comment: Kindly read my question... i am also asking someone to help me.

Comment: Help us to help you! Tell us what "not working" means. At least let us know what kind of error you get. - And what are you trying to achieve using the **Wi-Fi** MAC address?

Comment: ok JimmyB Check the link.
here is the simple example link of app from github 
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothChat
in this app when we select connect to Insecure device from option menu a dialog open and when you click the scan devices which gives the list or set of available devices. the list of available devices is shown in api 22 and lower but not shown in api 23 and greater... what is the problem and what is the solution...?

Comment: So your problem is that a list of available devices is not displayed by the app, no error message or someting?

Comment: yes there is no error message or somthing.